# Cell brackets on left side?

Tags: front-end, notebooks

Is it possible to have the cell brackets on the left? I looked through the options and couldn't find anything, but maybe it's some kind of esoteric style setting or something.

The reason I'm looking for this is because the content of notebooks is on the left, which means that's where my mouse hangs out most of the time. So I suspect having the cell brackets on the left would be more natural.

(I'm aware of the cellgroup openers, my question is about general selecting/manipulating, not just opening/closing).

Comment: I don't know the answer, but one strong indication that it might not be supported is that cell brackets grow with nesting depth whereas the left margin (for L->R languages) is supposed to have a fixed indent (for a given type of cell). In other words, if you have several sections/subsections/subsubsections etc., the cell brackets would be 6-7 layers deep, which would indent your input further and further to the right, leading to some unpleasant UI feel and experience. I wouldn't be surprised if the answer was "no", but I could be wrong.

Comment: The answer is, indeed, no.

Comment: @R.M., is there a problem with automatically shifting all cell brackets to the left as layers pile up?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> The answer is, indeed, no. – John Fultz

Comment: damn. i was hoping to leave this one hanging open-endedly silent on the shoulders of WRI, so that it would nag and scrape at their subconsciousnesses until there was no recourse but to implement this feature. but alas @Rojo you've forced my hand.